# Why can't I make a priority queue of type struct objects?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, priority-queue

So I kinda know that I can't make a priority queue with type struct but I don't exactly understand the reason why? I mean if you can create template classes to make your own type, why would a struct be any different?

This is what my code looks like in main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

struct DATA {
    std::string key;
    int data;
};

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<DATA> priorityQ;
    DATA newItem;
    newItem.key = "apples";
    newItem.data = 3;
    priorityQ.push(newItem);
    std::cout << priorityQ.top().key << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press the 'ENTER' key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The error come up with:

```
Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand
operand of type 'const DATA' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
TestProj    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 
14.0\vc\include\xstddef    Line: 240
```

I tried making this operator overload:

```
bool operator<(const DATA& a, const DATA& b) {
    return a.data > b.data;
}
```

But it still does not compile...

My question is: is it possible to put struct objects in priority queues and , and if not, why?

Comment: The `operator<` overload should be all you need. Where did you place it? Did you define, or at least declare it before you tried to make the `priority_queue`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/FISfMN

Comment: Oh! I'm such an idiot, this took me so long trying to figure it out (since i simplified this from a larger project I'm working on), but I declared the operator overloading function in the header file, and the header file was declared before the struct.... moved it between the struct and main and bam its working... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

struct DATA {
    std::string key;
    int data;
    // EITHER THIS
    bool operator<(const DATA & d2) const {return <your logic here>;}

};
// OR THIS
bool operator<(const DATA &d1, const DATA & d2){return <your logic here>;}


int main() {
    std::priority_queue<DATA> priorityQ;
    DATA newItem;
    newItem.key = "apples";
    newItem.data = 3;
    priorityQ.push(newItem);
    std::cout << priorityQ.top().key << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press the 'ENTER' key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/uC6JdB